# How to set value obtained in array of dictionary as current title of button without using tags

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I am getting a dictionaries in array as response from service.I want the starting 6 elements to show as the title of button.how this can be done?
tHE Dictionary obtained are as follows:

```
(   
 {
            Id = 43;
            Name = “ABX ";
        },
            {
            Id = 44;
            Name = “BLAX”;
        },
            {
            Id = 45;
            Name = “KAR ";
        },
            {
            Id = 46;
            Name = “JOHN”;
        },
            {
            Id = 19;
            Name = “LAMNO ";
        },
            {
            Id = 47;
            Name = "Togo ";
        },
            {
            Id = 48;
            Name = “XERIAN”;
        },
            {
            Id = 49;
            Name = “LAHG”;
        },
            {
            Id = 50;
            Name = “FHJJK”;
        },
            {
            Id = 51;
            Name = “ZAMBI”;
        },
            {
            Id = 52;
            Name = “ISAW ";
        }
    )
```

I have six buttons on viewcontroller and I want to set starting six key value for @"name" as current title of button.Please help to do this.

Comment: is this a json? you want extract values from json? or is this an array containing serveral dictionary? and what is your problem exacly? do you want help with buttons or extracting values?

Comment: I have edited the question now...I want help in setting the title of buttons.I have actually six buttons on a viewcontroller and I want to use starting six values obtained as response for key "name" as the current title of those buttons.

Comment: Put the buttons in an array using "referencing outlet collection"

Comment: Why you don't want to use tags of the button? Another way (may be not a nice approach) is there but can you please explain what is your problem if you use tag

Comment: actually i have done it using tags....and then matching the id with tags,but the ids in one case come from 1-50 and in other case 60-100 and it goes against the condition.

Comment: @Paulw11 Kindly explain your comment..a little more

Comment: You can declare `@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!` and then assign your buttons to this outlet. You can then access the buttons from the array

Comment: @TestShroff is your issue resolved?

Comment: yes ..it is resolved now...now I am working on scroll view...and looking for some good tutorials ...can u suggest some good tutorials for it??

Answer (score 0):

you can create collection outlet by following code for your buttons

```
@IBOutlet var buttonCollection: [UIButton]!
```

then assign your buttons from storyboard to this variable.
then loop in your array an access each dictionary with it's index and assign each name property to button title, it would look like this

```
for (index, infoDic) in yourArray.enumerated() {
    let button = buttonCollection[index]
    if let title = infoDic["Name"] as? String {
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    }

}
```

NOTE: in this sample i assume that yourArray's count is exactly the same as your button's count

Comment: Can u please write the same code in objective c as I am fresher and I have no idea about swift and have started objective c also currently.